# Pull specific points from 4d array using vectors

Tags: arrays, r, multidimensional-array, vector

I have a 4-dimensional array that I need to pull specific values from. The specific values are from 2 stable dimensions and two that change. See example for better description.

```
 set.seed(5)
 array <- array(dim=c(20,3,10,5))
 array[,,,] <- runif(3000,0,50)
```

So I need to pull specific values from this array. The dimension 2 value will always be 3 and dimension 4 will always be 1, but the other values will change. I have vectors of what I need of each, but I don't know how to combine them.

```
 v1 <- c(1, 7, 10, 11, 3, 6, 20, 5, 5, 4)
 v2 <- c(1, 1, 4, 6, 2, 3, 9, 8, 7, 8)
```

so basically I need array[1,3,1,1], array[7,3,1,1], array [10,3,4,1], array[11,3,6,1] and so on.

```
 > array[1,3,1,1]
 [1] 40.8038
 > array[7,1,1,1]
 [1] 26.398
 > array[10,3,4,1]
 [1] 7.784153
 > array[11,3,6,1]
 [1] 31.50343
```

Is there a way to use v1 and v2 to specify these points? If I do array[v1,3,v2,1], it gives me a 10x10 block, but I only want 10 individual values.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution is to use a matrix of indices, one row per set of indices:

```
array[cbind(v1,3,v2,1)]

# [1] 40.803803 38.007126  7.784153 31.503427 28.722716 32.444720 16.527393 14.420411
# [9] 41.935482 36.993050
```